# SQLDate and SimpleDateFormat...ParseException

Tags: java, android, sql, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string to a java.sql.Date with the SimpleDateFormat but it keep giving me ParseException
Long story short, here is my code

```
String s = "Tue, 30 Jul 2013 14:56:17 GMT";
java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z").parse(s);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Obviously I skipped the try/catch block around the SimpleDateFormat but it keeps failing there with the ParseException...

It keeps giving me this message:

```
Unparseable date: "Tue, 30 Jul 2013 14:56:17 GMT" (at offset 0)
```

I'm losing my head with this one and I don't even know why.
If you don't know what the letters mean in the SimpleDateFormat, look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: How about posting the stracktrace?

Comment: I just ran your code myself and had 0 errors from what you posted.  Are you sure that is the code you are invoking.  You might assume that is the String being passed in, but it is possible it is not.

Comment: It was the locale, I did like Reimeus's answer and it worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input day (offset `0`) from your input `String` doesn't match the corresponding `String` from your default `Locale`, You could use

```
Date date = 
   new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(s);
```

Comment: It was that! Thank you a lot! You just saved my day, sir :D